# Parameters of the Muskingum-Cunge Model in HEC-HMS

Tags: modelling, hec-geohms, hec-hms

I'm trying to simulate the flow of a river in HEC-HMS and for the routing model, I have chosen to use Muskingum-Cunge. In preparing the model, I used HEC-GeoHMS.

When I got to check the parameters for the routing method in HEC-HMS, it did not contain the necessary index flow, left and right roughness coefficients, and cross-section. How can the input for these be obtained?

I have the data necessary for the other required information, so they're not much of a problem. I already tried checking the steps I made in HEC-GeoHMS to find out what I forgot to do, but can't seem to find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In hec-geohms you can do parameters>TR55 flow path segments
parameters>TR55 flow path parameters
parameters>TR55 export to excel

Check this info, make any changes, then in excel go to addons there should be one called TR55 export, this will bring it all back into Hec-GeoHMS

This should fill that all in, you can then export and bring it into Hec-HMS, or just manually copt what's in the excel sheet into Hec-HMS

Answer (score 1):

In the HEC-HMS 4.3 Users Manual I found the following text:

"The index flow should represent the expected maximum flow in the reach".

So could you put in some arbitrary flow for the index flow, run the model, look at the peak flow at the upstream end of the reach, enter that as the index flow and run it again. The you could and repeat this as you work your way down the watershed. The number of runs would depending on how many reaches are dependent on other upstream reaches.